# Set css before other css gets set with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I want to add a css transition with jquery:

```
object.css({ 'transition': 'margin 1000ms linear' });
```

I want to set the margin-left before the transition is added, so I can can animate it to another position.

```
object.css({
    "margin-left": 700,
});

object.css({
    "transition": "margin 1000ms linear",
    "margin-left": 0,
});
```

Sadly this doesn't work. The object stays at 0px margin-left.

How can this be done?

Comment: It's a click event. I tried it with setTimeout and it worked, but I'm sure there is a better solution then having a 1ms delay between the two calls.

Comment: I thought about that but I want to avoid it, as it would be the only class in my css file. My target is to solve it with JS/jQuery only.

Comment: `setTimeout` is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this solution will work; it leverages CSS keyframe animations. It is the only way I know how to do it without using a timeout or another library. Another solution may be use to jQuery.transit if you can; it is like jQuery.animate, except it leverages CSS animations instead. It also adds some handy CSS3 parameters to jQuery.css().

http://jsfiddle.net/9xw6V/

CSS

```
.element {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ff9933;
}

.animate {
    -webkit-animation: slide 5s; /* Safari 4+ */
    -moz-animation:    slide 5s; /* Fx 5+ */
    -o-animation:      slide 5s; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation:         slide 5s; /* IE 10+ */
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0%   { margin-left: 100px; }
  100% { margin-left: 0px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide {
  0%   { margin-left: 100px; }
  100% { margin-left: 0px; }
}
@-o-keyframes slide {
  0%   { margin-left: 100px; }
  100% { margin-left: 0px; }
}
@keyframes slide {
  0%   { margin-left: 100px; }
  100% { margin-left: 0px; }
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var element = $(".element");

    element.click(function() {
       element.addClass("animate");
    }).bind('oanimationend animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
       element.removeClass("animate");
    });
});
```

Comment: tried the JSFiddle on Safari 7 and Firefox 30 and doesn't work. Also it seem to me an overcomplicated solution...

Comment: I would agree that is a semi-complicated solution; however, it is due to the limitations of CSS. I just tried it in FF30 and Safari 7 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because the `transition` property is aquired by the browser **after** the object has been moved to 700px and then back to 0px.

You can fix your code this way:

```
object.css({
    "margin-left": 700,
});

setTimeout( function() {
    object.css({
        "transition": "margin 1000ms linear",
        "margin-left": 0,
    });
}, 0);
```

The first `css` call is excuted then the codes ends (after the `setTimeout` call)

The browser refresh the page and the object goes to 700px.

Then the second `css` call is executed as a callback of `setTimeout` and the `transition` property and the new position are acquired.

The JavaScript code ends again and the browser refresh the page moving the object to 0px slowly.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6KVNb/

Comment: Original poster is aware of this "hack," but has opted for a more standard solution. See comments on original post.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can toggle the `transition` with css, but you need to cause a repaint for the change to take effect. This is easily done with a `setTimeout()` but that will interfere with your object chaining. Another method is to quickly show/hide the element, which I've used below. Give this jquery extension method a shot:

```
$.fn.cssNow = function(){
   var $t = $(this),
      _args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0);
   return this.addClass("trans-none")
              .hide(0, function() {
                  $.fn.css.apply($t, _args);
                  $t.hide(0,function(){
                      $t.show().removeClass("trans-none");
                  });
              });    
}
```

I opted to use a class instead of setting the css directly, but only to skip the step of saving the original definition. You could leave the class out if you wanted and use `setProperty()` instead (which lets you specify `!important`).

```
.trans-none { 
    transition: none !important;
}
```

Then your code would look something like this (assuming transition is set on object to start):

```
object
   .cssNow({"margin-left":"700px"})
   .css({"margin-left":"0px"});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9zbc/

Answer (score 0):

Use `animate()` instead.

```
object.css({
    "margin-left": 700,
});
object.animate({"marginLeft": 0}, 1000, 'linear');
```

Also `animate()` receives a callback once complete making it great to chain animations:

```
object.animate(
   {"margin-left": 700},
   500,
   'linear',
   function(){
       object.animate({ "margin-left": 0},  1000, 'linear');
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I already did this. My plugin has an option to use ether jQuery animation or css transition. The jQuery part is made with animate.